# how to use CIBERSORT

Tags: rna-seq, cibersort

I have seen in several articles, the use of [CIBERSORT](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41587-019-0114-2) to calculate the proportion of immune system cells using gene expression data, I would like to try it but I have not found how to install it for R, I have tried to register on the website but it doesn't allow me to enter after introduing my e-mail and password.

Comment: Could you clarify the issue ?